# Automatically provide data to Express partial views

Tags: node.js, express, partials

I'm writing an [Express 4](http://expressjs.com/) app, and am currently using [twig.js](https://github.com/justjohn/twig.js) as the view engine since I find it comfortable, though I could be persuaded to change this engine.

I've done a lot of development with PHP/Laravel and have gotten used to what in that camp they call [view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers). Using these I can write a composer for a particular view, whether it's a main page view, a layout which other views extend, or a partial other views include. The composer does any necessary logic to prepare whatever data the view needs, and then attaches it to the view's context so it's available during rendering.

For example, I might have a partial which shows the current user status, so if they're logged out it'll maybe have just a log in button, and if they're logged in it'll have their icon, username, and a menu to let them log out etc. The corresponding composer would check to see if a user is logged in, and if so attach the relevant data about the user to the view's context. It then doesn't matter which page includes this partial; the data will always be available without me having to remember to add that specific data to the context passed to the page's main view.

Is there some equivalent in Express? Or does it depend on the template engine I'm using?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, views that are rendered using [`res.render()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render) need to have their data passed in on every `res.render()`. If the view uses a partial template that requires certain data points, the view that uses that template will need to have that value passed in through `res.render()`. So in short, you always need to pass the data in regardless if the data point is required by a partial template that might be shared. When using view engines, nothing is automatically provided to the view.

Comment: Do you agree that this seems awkward in certain cases, like the one I outlined in my question? I wonder if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: @tremby A large portion of Web Sites/Apps built using Express use some other framework to provide data binding like React or Angular (i.e. the MEAN Stack).

Comment: This is not entirely true. You can use [response locals](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals) and [application locals](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals). I always include the following middleware into my express aplications: `function(req, res, next){
            res.locals.req  = req;
            
            next(); }`

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking if it's possible to have some view A, that includes partial P_A and be able to pass some data to the partial that's not dependent on routing, i.e wherever you are on the site / app your partial has data bound to it (totally independent of both the route / url and view ) which you could use for your logged in status ?

if so then  create your partial, let's use a navigation / menu partial:
**please note that this example uses ejs for templating**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
    <!-- pass the data upon call / include-->
    <% for(var i = 0, len=navigation.length;i < len;i++) {%>
        <li><a href="<%=navigation[i].href%>"><%=navigation[i].Text%></a></li>
    <%}%>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Call  / Include your patial on a view**

## view.ejs

```
<%- include('nav', { navigation : [{Text : 'Items' ,href : '/' },{Text : 'People' ,href : '/names' }] } )%>
```

Comment: This is unclear to me. It doesn't appear to be answering the question, but I could be misunderstanding it. I'm asking for some way for particular data (producing which may involve database lookups and that sort of thing) to be available for a particular partial view, whenever and wherever that partial view is included. It looks here like you're just showing how to pass some data from a parent view to a partial. Please clarify if I'm missing something.

Comment: Hi, What I was trying to demonstrate, and I might be the one with the misunderstanding, is that, if you have a navigation as in a menu as an example, and say you are pulling it's data from the db, you could have a nav partial as shown in my answer and already do the logic in it then include the partial in an actual view where you pass the data from your db as needed. the navigation json object is just an example, that would be your db object for instance. Still confusing ?

Comment: Oh, so you're saying embed application logic in the code of the partial view?

Comment: Of-course, and that's also dependent on how you like organizing / separating things in your app... you do have an option of writing the logic in your controller and call it in the partial...but if there's not much happening in terms of the amount of code to achieve what you want, you can indeed write the logic in the partial, in my example, there really isn't logic but just a loop, which could possibly be the case with you as well.

Comment: Some code snippet closer to what you need:

'loginStatusPartial' partial:
<div class="userWidget">
  <% if(isUserLoggedIn)  {%>
  <div class="loggedIn">//to do with loggedin users<div/>
<%} else {%>
  <div class="loggedOut">//to do with loggedin users<div/>
<% } %>
</div>

'View' code - where partial will be called / included:
<%- include('loginStatusPartial', { isUserLoggedIn : true} )%>

Sorry, you might need to extract this comment and have a cleaner look of what the code  looks like.

Comment: I don't want to write application logic in a partial. I can't even do that in certain templating languages anyway, and that is enforced by design to separate code from presentation. "you do have an option of writing the logic in your controller and call it in the partial" -- can you expand on this, in the context of my original question? I want this logic to run any time this partial is included, no matter where it's included from, but never when it is not included.

Comment: Create a controller and write Logic for your partial the way you would with a view. " I don't want to write application logic in a partial. I can't even do that in certain templating languages anyway" I imagined you were flexible with changing if what you are using does not do the job " I'm writing an Express 4 app, and am currently using twig.js as the view engine since I find it comfortable, though I could be persuaded to change this engine.".

Comment: Sure, but how is that controller then called automatically whenever the view is included? You're right that I said I could be persuaded to change the view engine, but that would be to have the "view composers" feature, not to allow me to break the MVC convention and write application logic right in the view.

Comment: Well, instantiate the controller in your partial / view as you would normally do programmatically to have access to your controller's logic.

Comment: But that requires me to know which routes and under which conditions the partial is included, does it not?

Comment: That's sort of the point, how would you not know where your code should run ? you write it with intention right ? Like, I am going to have an Apple Controller which gets called when someone wants an Apple... I feel like you left out some 'meat' to your question as you seem like you aren't just struggling with what you pointed out on your initial question, there seems to be more that I feel you need help with, which, really, if you could be upfront then we would know what exactly you need help with.

Comment: When working on my own, I don't want to have to double check I've removed all now-unnecessary code from the controller if a chunk of markup is removed. I don't want to have to duplicate logic in the controller and view such as in a case where some back-end calculation work is necessary only under particular conditions known to the view. When working with a front-end developer I want them to be able to use partials I provide wherever they like without support from me to edit the controllers every time the design changes.

Comment: At the moment, how do you achieve "When working with a front-end developer I want them to be able to use partials I provide wherever they like without support from me..." ? If we can go back to my initial response, what part did you not understand ? I would really be happy to get to a point where you are helped than arguing / exchanging ideas that don't really help you as you came in for help.

Comment: At the moment I do not achieve that in node/express, which is why I am asking this question. I achieve it in Laravel in PHP as explained in my question. As for what I don't understand about your answer, I just don't think it answers the question unless I'm okay with putting application logic in a partial view, which I am not.

Comment: You can write your logic wherever you want , the point is you will instantite or make a reference to whereever your logic is sitting , unless you are  using functions and not classes, you need to create that controiller and pass the partial name in your return statement in your laravel app , if the question is still how, I don't know, under normal circumstances a person knows where the things they write / create in their app will be used.

Comment: Not sure what it is you're saying about Laravel there. I define a view composer corresponding to a particular partial, and then wherever the front-end developer includes that partial, the composer runs and attaches whatever data to the partial's context. It doesn't need extra back-end code.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is nothing like that in expressjs.

Comment: So what would you do in this situation? Attach the same data in a whole bunch of route action files, since it's used on so many pages?

Comment: Depend on the use case. Authentication for example if handled with Passport will add a `user` attribute to the request object witch is available on the context of view rendering. If is specific for the path (for example all pages related to a client with the client ID on the url as /:clientID/some-stuff) i suggest using [route parameters](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router.param) witch are available on the context of view rendering and for other cases a route middleware may be a solution.